# What do the curly braces mean in a MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql, business-objects

I have query from Business Object report that run in MySQL database

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`date_type_column` date DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `mytable`(`date_type_column`) VALUES ('2019-01-02');
INSERT INTO `mytable`(`date_type_column`) VALUES ('2020-01-02');
INSERT INTO `mytable`(`date_type_column`) VALUES ('2021-01-02');
INSERT INTO `mytable`(`date_type_column`) VALUES ('2022-01-02');


SELECT
*
FROM
`mytable`
WHERE
date_type_column >= {d '2021-01-01 00:00:00'};
```

the question is what does `{d '2022-02-01 00:00:00'}` syntax actually mean in this statemen ?  It may be not correct SQL syntax but the query works "as is" in MySQL workbench 8.0. MySQL 5.7.39.

Comment: That's not valid MySQL syntax. Maybe it's something added by Business Objects.

Comment: There's no need for the curly braces. Just write `>= '2022-02-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: @Barmar the query works "as is" in MySQL workbench 8.0 . I haven't found any MYSQL documentation about the syntax {d '2022-02-01 00:00:00'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *ODBC escape* syntax. It's described in the [Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html) documentation:

> *{identifier expr}* is ODBC escape syntax and is accepted for ODBC compatibility. The value is *expr*. The `{` and `}` curly braces in the syntax should be written literally; they are not metasyntax as used elsewhere in syntax descriptions.

SQL-Server uses the *identifier* to determine how to parse *expr*. `d` is used to create `DATE` literals. See the SQL-Server documentation [Date, Time, and Timestamp Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/date-time-and-timestamp-literals?view=sql-server-ver16). But MySQL ignores the identifier.

I can't explain why the query doesn't work for 2022 dates, it should be no different from writing

```
WHERE
mytable.mydate_Type_column >= '2022-02-01 00:00:00'
```

without the curly braces.

Comment: ok. it make sense. the only question what is d in {d .  the query is not working only with {'2022-02-01 00:00:00'}. I see that I can put any number of characters here instead of d.

Comment: The `d` is for `date`

Comment: the query works same way if I put any other char instead of d date_type_column >= {tghghg '2021-01-01 00:00:00'}

Comment: Of course. As I said, MySQL ignores that part.